# Cannot seem to use CGRectIntegral and CGRectInset functions in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry for the novice question.

But just as the title says, I can't seem to use these functions in Swift 3. I have tried by importing the CoreGraphics library, but to no avail.

Does anyone know why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After importing CoreGraphics , it worked fine ... i checked in xcode 8, swift 3..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The functions are working fine, but their names have changed (a bit):

```
  let frame = CGRect.zero
  let x = frame.integral
  frame.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
```

Comment: I have not checked but, i guess you can use it like this
attributes.frame = attributes.frame.integral

Answer (score 5):

1. > import CoreGraphics
2. `let rect = CGRect()
    let rectIntegral = rect.integral`

Thanks:)

Answer (score 4):

Actually you don't need to import CoreGraphics.

In Swift 3 Objective-C function

```
CGRect CGRectIntegral(CGRect rect)
```

has become

```
var integral: CGRect { get }
```

and

```
CGRect CGRectInset(CGRect rect, CGFloat dx, CGFloat dy);
```

has become

```
func insetBy(dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat) -> CGRect
```

Both API have to be called on the `CGRect` instance for example

```
let newFrame = view.frame.insetBy(dx: 10.0, dy:10.0)
```

---

A hint to find out yourself

- Press <kbd>⇧⌘0</kbd>
- Type <kbd>CGRectIn</kbd> in the search field
- In the popup menu set the language to Objective C
- Select one of the functions
- Set the language to Swift